# Kubernetes on Azure AKS secrets for Docker Hub missing after autoscaling

Tags: kubernetes, dockerhub, azure-aks

I am dealing with some issues on Kubernetes on Azure (AKS) using Autoscaler and secrets for pulling images from Docker Hub.
I created the secret in my applications namespace while having 3 nodes enabled (initial cluster status).

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry mysecret --docker-server=https://index.docker.io/v1/ --docker-username=<docker_id> --docker-password=<docker_password> -n mynamespace
```

I deploy my application using the imagePullSecrets option after specifying images URL.

```
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: mysecret
```

After deploying the application I created the autoscaler rule.

```
kubectl autoscale deployment mydeployment --cpu-percent=50 --min=1 --max=20 -n mynamespace
```

All new pods pull the image correctly. However at some point when new Kubernetes node is being automatically deployed, all new pods requiring the DockerHub based image can not start.

```
Failed to pull image "mydocherhubaccount/myimage:mytag": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: pull access denied for mydocherhubaccount/myimage:mytag, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

Is there anything I am missing here? I waited for 15 minutes and recreated pods but it did not help.

I use Kubernetes 1.15.5 on Azure AKS. The cluster was created using the following command.

```
az aks create -g myresourcegroup -n mynamespace --location eastus --kubernetes-version 1.15.5 --node-count 3 --node-osdisk-size 100 --node-vm-size Standard_D4_v3 --enable-vmss --enable-cluster-autoscaler --min-count 3 --max-count 5
```

I appreciate any help provided. It really got me stuck here.

Comment: Please, edit your question and add your yaml files to it. I would like to take a look at it. Could you share the output of this command: `kubectl describe mydeployment`?